# properties of constructor function

Tags: javascript

In [this](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js) jQuery plugin, there's a constructor function called `$.jPlayer` (line 64)
There are also properties and methods - `$.jPlayer.htmlEvent` and `$.jPlayer.convertTime`.
They don't belong to constructor function's prototype. What object do they belong to?
How are they used? Are they transferred to the instances of `$.jPlayer`  constructor function?

Comment: In JavaScript, functions are objects, so they can have properties as well. E.g. some default properties are `prototype`, `call` and `bind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Who they belong to?

   To the jPlayer "class". Class variables are a way to store things you don't think need to be visible as properties of every instance.
2. How are they used?

   Just refer to them directly, as you yourself do in the original question.  For example, there is this snippet in line 996

   ```
   $.each($.jPlayer.htmlEvent, function(i, eventType) {
       mediaElement.addEventListener(this, function() {
           if(entity.gate) {
               self._trigger($.jPlayer.event[eventType]);
           }
       }, false);
   });
   ```

   where `$.jplayer.htmlEvent` is used as a kind of global constant (but without polluting the actual global namespace, since its stored as a class variable).
3. Are they transferred to the instances?

   Only if you explicitely do that (although it probably isn't done if it was decided to store them as class attributes instead of prototype attributes in the first place)